# Clip line to shape of circle node

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I am trying to have a line divide a circle node at a certain point, but the way I have come up still leaves a small amount of line outside the circle, as seen below. I tried using `clip`, but I wasn't able to extract a usable path from the node.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,fit,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \node[baseline] (f1p) {\({f_{1}'}(x)\)};
        \node[baseline, right =3mm of f1p] (f1) {\(f_1\)};
        \node[circle,draw,fit={(f1p)(f1)}] (f1c) {};
        \coordinate (f1m) at ($(f1p.east)!0.5!(f1.west)$);
        \draw (f1c.north-|f1m) -- (f1c.south-|f1m);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: lines clipping]

Edit:
As it was unclear in the original Question, I am looking for a way for this type of division of the circle to work with any length of text on either side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `intersections` library. Instead of using `\draw` for the vertical line, use `\path`. For the circle and line use `name path=`, then `\draw` the line from `intersection-1` to `intersection-2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,fit,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \node[baseline] (f1p) {\(f_1'(x)\)};
        \node[baseline, right =3mm of f1p] (f1) {\(f_1\)};
        \node[name path=cir,circle,draw,fit={(f1p)(f1)}] (f1c) {};
        \coordinate (f1m) at ($(f1p.east)!0.5!(f1.west)$);
        \path[name path=ver] (f1c.north-|f1m) -- (f1c.south-|f1m);
        \draw [name intersections={of=cir and ver}] (intersection-1)--(intersection-2);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sadly, this won't work when using longer text, which I am using in other variations of this figure.

Comment: @Dexterous: I understand. I changed my answer. I assume you want the `scope` for some other reason since it doesn't do anything as it is now.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a `path picture` which automatically gets clipped against the path (here just the `circle` node).

This has a few disadvantages:

- Filling the circle shape gets complicated (but since the node is drawn after the text this will need a different approach anyway).
- The text nodes shouldn't be rotated.

There are solutions to both but they are a bit more complicated. (And at some point, I'd just develop a separate shape.)

---

I've removed the `baseline` options, they don't do anything here. If you want the whole TikZ picture to be vertically aligned at the base of its nodes add `anchor=base` to the node and `baseline` to the `tikzpicture`.

I'm using zero `inner sep`s for the text nodes so that `circle vsplit distance` is taken between the text whereas the circle node uses the default `inner sep` (.3333em) which means that the circle is fitted as if the it actually had the text inside it.

(The way you did means that the distance between the text is actually 2 * .3333em + 3mm and the circle node has basically an inner sep of .6666em around the actual text.)

I've added a second example that creates the alignment of your original code.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  circle vsplit distance/.initial=3mm,
  circle vsplit fit/.style={circle, draw},
  circle vsplit/.style={
    inner sep=+0pt,
    label={[anchor=base west,inner sep=+0pt,name=\tikzlastnode-r,
           xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circle vsplit distance}]base east:{#1}},
    append after command={
      node[fit=(\tikzlastnode)(\tikzlastnode-r),name=\tikzlastnode-c,
           circle vsplit fit, path picture={
        \draw ([xshift={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circle vsplit distance})/2}]%
          \tikzlastnode.east) {coordinate (@)} % {} for \tikzlastnode
          (\tikzlastnode-c.north-|@) -- (\tikzlastnode-c.south-|@);}]{}}}
]
\node[circle vsplit=$f_1$] (f1) {$f'_1(x)$};
\path[circle vsplit distance=3mm+.6666em,
      circle vsplit fit/.append style={inner sep=.6666em}]
  node[circle vsplit=$f_2$] (f2) at (2,0) {$f'_2(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I was looking for something more like [Sandy G's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671543/288264). Thank you very much for answering though.

Comment: @Dexterous I might have missed the point of your question then. But maybe it helps others.